# Android Room how to search by text when using DataSource.Factory?

Tags: android, android-room, android-pagedlistview

In my project using `PagedListAdapter` for pagination and the app also able to search by keyword.

> DAO.kt

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE name LIKE :keyword")
fun getItems(keyword: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, ItemEntity>
```

> Create

```
lateinit var itemLivePagedList: LiveData<PagedList<Item>>

.
.
.

val dataSourceFactory = itemUseCase.getItems(keyword)
val boundaryCallback = MyBoundaryCallback(itemUseCase, compositeDisposable, PAGE_SIZE)
itemLivePagedList = LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, pagedListConfig)
            .setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback)
            .build()
```

How can I update the list when keyword changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `keyword` changes, you have to call `itemUseCase.getItems(keyword)` again.

Look at [this project](https://github.com/mirmilad/PagingSearchFood). it has been written in Java but it shows how to implement a search scenario with PagingLibrary.

For more details see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733316/1162154).